# Executing a called php script as if it was in the same working directory as the calling script

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, directory-structure, working-directory

Is there a trick to running a php script as if it was in a different directory than the one it's currently in ?

I'm trying to organise the file structure of a small program into folders that have more semantic meaning to me, but in doing so I seem to be working against php's concept of current working directories.

### Context

file structure:

```
| function/
|         function.php
|
| fragment/
|         import.php
|         export.php
|
| index.php
```

All of the php files require function.php

```
<?php require_once 'function/function.php'; ?>
```

including fragments inside index.php works just fine :

```
<?php include 'fragment/import.php'; ?>
<?php include 'fragment/export.php'; ?>
```

they all happily find function/function.php thanks to index.php being executed in the base working directory.

### However,

if I get fragment/import.php by calling it from index.php with a XMLHttpRequest script, it can no longer find function.php since the current working directory has now changed to fragment/ and it's looking for fragment/function/function.php

I'm currently using `chdir()` inside each of the fragment/ files to navigate back up to the base directory. But my OCD-sense is tingling.

```
// plus I have to hardcode the target directory
chdir( '/www/code/laboratory/' );

// as this makes bad things happen for the include in index.php
chdir( dirname( __dir__ );
// same as
include '../function/function.php';
```

Put simply, I wouldn't be having any of these problems if the .php files were all in the same directory. Not to mention that it irks me to no end that the program is calling a script that has to explicitly tell itself to go back to the directory it was called from, it seems so unnecessary.

It's causing so much hassle that I must be doing something wrong. I tried fiddling with a .htaccess file, but didn't get very far. It appears that RewriteRule only works with http requests anyway and not php includes, so I kinda gave up on that idea. Using the <base> tag from html, alas, didn't work out either as the fragments aren't full html documents and have no header. Perhaps there is a way to set <base> using setRequestHeader() in the XMLHttpRequest but I couldn't find it.

### TLDR;

Could there be a trick to making the scripts inside fragments/ think that they're in the same working directory as index.php ? Alternatively, is there something that can be done with the XMLHttpRequest header to let the script know which directory I want it to run in ?

Or should I be thinking in php logic, not semantics, and dividing up my code is a real bad idea ?

Any tips and advice are welcome. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `__DIR__` offers some sort of guarantee of the result (it will always be the directory the script is in). Working with relative paths or `getcwd()` does not. Use these responsibly.

Comment: Have you considered using OOP and autoloading? GIves you a lot more flexibility for structure.

Comment: @apokryfos : Yeah, too many relative paths that should probably be absolute could be making this a lot more complicated than it should. I was considering putting an install_dir variable in a settings.ini and using that to make everything absolute.

@ Jeremy Harris : funnily enough, I use objects all the time in javascript but I still write php like it was basic... I'd have to look into that.

Comment: @slartibartfast If you are using Apache to serve the page then `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is a path that is the site's root directory based on the apache configuration so you may also rely on that one.

Comment: @apokryfos Indeed. Although to be honest if I start injecting constants and variables all over the place I'd probably rather put everything together and be done with it... messy files > messy code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding to the **include path** where PHP searches for includes?

```
$path = '/www/code/laboratory/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

[Read more Documentation on that here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Comment: Yes, or you could more easily maintain that if it were in your function/function.php file, perhaps.  Note you can add several directories, too.  Would you mind marking this as the solution, if it has helped you, please?

Comment: Hadn't thought of looking at the problem from the 'include' angle...
interestingly enough, I can set the include path from a .htaccess file:

`php_value include_path ".:/foo/bar"`

Ideally though, the scripts would like to access the same directory structure as index.php, there are other directories like 'data' and 'template' that I left out of the example, my bad.

Your answer does work for the question I asked though. I'd accept it for future reference if there isn't a better way. Thank you.

Comment: Simply add all of the individual paths using PATH_SEPERATOR (which is probably going to be comma or semi-colon, but you don't have to know that). so at the top of functions.php (since it is always called, or near the top of index.php if it is always called **set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $inc_path1 . PATH_SEPARATOR . $inc_path2 . PATH_SEPARATOR . $inc_path3 . PATH_SEPARATOR . $inc_path4 );** then you can cover all your folders where you are putting includes.

Comment: By the way, as one moves from functional programming to object oriented programming, *all the rage* about **auto-loading** is uncovered (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) - when one creates classes and instantiates them ($obj = new myClass()) then the auto-loader calls the require() on their class file so code isn't littered with "finding files".  it's pretty amazing, really.  The next iteration of that is **use**, but getting familiar with auto-loading is a first step.

Comment: @ WEBjuju That's pretty nifty, if it wasn't for the little arrows I wouldn't have thought it was php =)
As per the set_include_path solution, what I meant to say was that the fragments are looking for data/ and template/ folders in the base directory for files, not for includes. They find function.php thanks to the set_include_path but their working directory is still the same and have to `chdir()` out of fragment/ to get the files they're looking for... I hope that makes sense.

Comment: you should not need the chdir(), just ask to include/require the file by basename only after setting the locations where php may find the files.

Comment: Wow thanks for taking the time to screencast ^^
there's still something I'm not quite getting in your answer though. If export.php wants to, say, run a scandir( 'data/' ) in the same working directory as index.php then setting the include path doesn't stop it from scanning it's own location. Having said that, I can use get_include_path() as some sort of constant, like `foreach( scandir( get_include_path() . $url ) as $file ) { ... }` that seems a bit odd though.

Comment: is this a new question?  anyway, get_include_path is going to return something like **.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear** which as you see is directories separated by colon, the separator.  Since scandir() takes the directory (single directory) as a string, you will have to do something else - but again, that's a new question - hopefully this one is answered now.

Comment: Yeah. agreed. Thank you for taking the time to answer and putting up with my rantings =)